# CreateAsyncThunk Problem with 400 Bad request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

i have created a asyncthunk, but when status code is 400, the result of request is still fulfilled, which method is to handle a 400 error with createasyncthunk and fetch api?

This is a action code:

```
    import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authService from "./auth-service";


// Get user from localStorage
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initialState = {
  user: user ? user : "",
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

// Register user
export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/signup",
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await authService.register(user);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

// Login user
export const login = createAsyncThunk("auth/login", async (user, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    return await authService.login(user);
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString();
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
  }
});

export const logout = createAsyncThunk("auth/logout", async () => {
  await authService.logout();
});

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.message = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(register.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(register.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.user = "";
      })
      .addCase(register.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        state.user = "";
      })
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.user = "";
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

This is a service code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/";


const token = Cookies.get('XSRF-Token')

// Register user
const register = async (userData) => {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL + "signup", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      'Accept': "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
  });

  const responseData = await response.json();

  if (response.ok) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(responseData));
    return responseData;
  }
};

// Login user
const login = async (userData) => {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL + "login", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      'Accept': "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  const responseData = await response.json();

  if (response.ok) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(responseData));
    return responseData;
  }
};

// Logout user
const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
};

const authService = {
  register,
  logout,
  login,
};

export default authService;
```

The problem is both register and login action, return a fulfilled even if the code of post request is 400 and my intention is send a message about error

Comment: Can you show the relevant code that illustrates the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't do anything if `response.ok` is not truthy.  That's what will happen when you get a 4xx status.

So, for example, in this code:

```
// Register user
const register = async (userData) => {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL + "signup", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      'Accept': "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    // body: JSON.stringify(userData),
  });

  const responseData = await response.json();

  if (response.ok) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(responseData));
    return responseData;
  }
};
```

You just allow the `async` function to have an `undefined` return value if `response.ok` is not truthy.  That will resolve the promise, with an `undefined` resolved value.

Perhaps, you want to turn any non-2xx status into a rejection like this:

```
// Register user
const register = async (userData) => {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL + "signup", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      'Accept': "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    // body: JSON.stringify(userData),
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const responseData = await response.json();
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(responseData));
  } else {
    // reject the promise
    throw new Error(`status code ${response.status}`)
  }

  
};
```

You would probably want to do something similar for all your uses of `fetch()`.

Since I find that I want this to be the standard behavior when making requests, I have my own `fetchWrapper()` function that automatically converts any non-2xx status to a promise rejection so I don't have to code that into every use of `fetch()`.

---

Here's an example of a fetchWrapper function that turns any http status that is not in the range of 200-299 into a rejected promise:

```
async function fetchJSON(url, options) {
    let response = await fetch(url, options);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`status code ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice and for your kindness

Comment: if it possible can you share your code of fetchwrapper?

Comment: @zeltarave - I added a sample wrapper function.